How to set different environment in angular application while using proxy.conf.js?
I am using proxy.conf.js in my angular project. I want to set different variable for different environment for dev, prod and qa. How to set different env using proxy. Do I need to use environment.ts or environment.prod.ts file?a
proxy.conf.js code
const TARGET = {
  "target": 'http://localhost:20151',
  "secure": false
};

const PROXY_CONFIG = {
  "/weatherforecast": TARGET,
  "/login": TARGET,
  "/logout": TARGET,
  "/api/v1/Account/register": TARGET,
  "/api/v1/Account/manage/info": TARGET,
  "/api/v1/MasterData/ApproxFullTruckLoadPerYearLimits": TARGET,
  "/api/v1/MasterData/TrucksOwnedOrManaged": TARGET,
  "/api/v1/MasterData/WareHouseSpaceManagedInSqMeter": TARGET,
  "/api/v1/MasterData/CountryDetails": TARGET,
};

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;

angular.json code build and serve

        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "freight-web-app-ang:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "freight-web-app-ang:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development",
          "options": {
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.js"
          }
          
        },

